# How to get live EEG data from ActiView706?

Tags: matlab, eeglab

I want to get the live EEG data from ActiView706 in order to process it and send the processed data via a server upon a request from a client. The data is recorded from the subject that is in a VR environment and I need to get it.

My problem is I don't know how to access that data received as input for the ActiView software or the data in it. Is there any way of accessing the source code of the software or to get the brainwaves displayed in the GUI (preferably labeled somehow)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXlP3.jpg)

As shown above is what the GUI is displaying and what I intend on doing is having the subject control the environment using his brainwaves and that is why I need to access, process and send them to a Unity client (The trial environment is made in Unity).

Comment: Sounds like a big project, you forgot to ask a question though... please take the [tour] and read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer through a colleague of mine that referred me to the biosemi website where they have an example TcpClient for the softwares' server. This is the example:

https://www.biosemi.com/download/TcpIpClientMatlabV1.zip